# Threads and Observer Pattern

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns, thread-safety

I am trying to write Observe pattern in Java in multithread program to develop own logging program. My program is used in any Java class and can create the `Logger` class, and write a message to the logger. Logger class will call the logger manager class , which is a Singleton class and it also have the private class which is thread, on execution a scheduler runs, So I kept that execution in the private constructor.

```
private void LoggerManager() { 
    System.out.println("IN CONSTRUCTOR"); 
    executorThread.submit(new CreateLoggerFileForSpecifiedTime());
}

static LoggerManager getInstance() {
    if (LOGMANAGER == null) {
        synchronized (LoggerManager.class) {
            if(LOGMANAGER == null){
                System.out.println("IN MANAGER");
                LOGMANAGER = new LoggerManager();
            }
        }
    }
    return LOGMANAGER;
}
```

Next there is a method in the LoogerManager "writeMessageToLog".

```
void writeMessageToLog(String componantName, String message, 
                     Calendar messageCreationTime) { 
    LoggerDetails logDetails = new LoggerDetails(componantName, message,
                     messageCreationTime); 
    LogInitiater logIntiater = new LogInitiater(logDetails, noticeOfLoggerChange, 
                     noticeOfMessageAdded); 
    executorThread.submit(logIntiater); 
}
```

`LogIntitiater` is a thread which is added the LogWriter to two Subject's, One subject is a scheduler I have pasted above i.e a Timer runs for every specified time and notfiies `LogWriter` the need to create a new log file while the other purpose is when a message is added in the queue. Code is not working as expected:
* scheduler code is not running, I tried with `execute` as well. That private constructor is not being called
* thread initiater is not always called
* observe pattern:  I have used J2SE interfaces i.e `Observable` and `Observe` and they are not working as expected

Please help me.

Comment: I accepted all the answer which resolved my question. How can I accept the answer without solving my problem

Comment: fine I was just saying. By the way are you trying to make Logger asynchronous here?

Comment: Ya, Yes you are correct. Is there any other solution. Please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Producer - Consumer way for Logger **(INCOMPLETE AND NOT FULLY TESTED) - will leave that to you**

This is just for the demonstration purpose and shows one way of doing ASYNCHRONOUS logging

```
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

class Logger extends Thread{
        private static Logger logger = null;
        private BlockingQueue<String> logRequests;

        private Logger(){
            logRequests = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(10000);
        }

        public static Logger getLogger(){
            if(logger == null){
                synchronized (Logger.class) {
                    logger = new Logger();
                    logger.start();
                }
            }
            return logger;
        }


        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Starting to log");
            while(true){
                try {
                    System.out.println(logRequests.take());
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    //interrupted so stop logging
                    System.out.println("Logger exiting");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        public void info(String logMessage){
            //not taken care of the case when queue becomes full
            //will leave it to you
            logRequests.add(logMessage);
        }
    }
```

Main class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger.getLogger().info("This is info message");

        System.out.println("I am free");


        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            //stop the log
        Logger.getLogger().interrupt();

    }
```

Comment: Above solution works fine on stand alone. But I need aditional task as well, Need to write the message in the log file. And Every 10 minutes I need to change the log file as well. And Message should be in the Order of the request comes, and nothing should be stooped at the file creation time.

Comment: yes :) but there are some cases like queue full that I have not handelled

Comment: Thank you Narendra, it worked, I have added your classes to root of my classes , it started working. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: That's what we are here to do :) Glad I could help you @Kumar